# Quick way to return object item after calling method?

Tags: php, object

I'm using PHP 5.4. Most of my database queries in my class return the results as an object. I have a few queries that I'm converting to return objects instead of an array. One of the queries I'm converting I used quite a bit in my application. Typically I only need to access one item at a time, and I use a shorthand method for accessing that array item.

```
echo $this->analysis->get_meta_data()['member_id'];
```

Is there a way to use this same method for only fetching a single result from the array with objects? I tried:

```
echo $this->analysis->get_meta_data()->member_id;
```

...thinking it would work but all I got was an error. I just didn't know if I could return an individual item from an object in a similar way as you can from an array. Thanks!

var_dump:

```
object(stdClass)#23 (72) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "31734"
  ["member_id"]=>
  string(1) "2233"
  ["entity_name"]=>
  string(15) "Tester, Test"
  ["create_date"]=>
  string(10) "11/13/2012"
  ["create_user_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["status_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ...
}
```

Comment: can you paste `var_dump($this->analysis->get_meta_data())` ?

Comment: `$this->analysis->get_meta_data()->member_id;` should work fine if the result of get_meta_data is that stdClass you show

Comment: please show code of `get_meta_data()`.

Comment: Just to know.. Of course you have tried with parenthesis..

    echo (($this->analysis)->get_meta_data())->member_id;

Comment: I appear to have made a typo in my code. `$this->analysis->get_meta_data()->member_id;` does, indeed, work.

Answer (score 3):

You could return an `ArrayObject` instead of `stdClass` from your `get_meta_data()` function and have the best of both worlds

```
function get_meta_data()
{
     // your existing code building an array

     // ..

     // hand array to ArrayObject, telling it to also allow array keys to be accessed as properties

     return new ArrayObject($array, ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);

}
//Either method should now work

echo $this->analysis->get_meta_data()['member_id']; 
echo $this->analysis->get_meta_data()->member_id;
```

Comment: yes, but that doesnt answer the question. If his get_meta_data method returns a stdClass object $this->foo()->propertyName should work

Comment: @Gordon, I see what you mean, fair point, the OP's code should work as is.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method that iterates over an array. And for each iteration, you move the index.

You also could do this:

```
    get_meta_data() {

         $obj->member_id = $var["member_id"];
         return $obj;

    }
}
class Obj {

    var $member_id;

}
```

I'm assuming that you already have `$obj` and `$var` somewhere in the class.